# What do you call equipment delivered as parts to be assembled on-site?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'd like to know what word I should use for an equipment/any item that comes in various pieces to be assembled on-site by the workers, instead of coming as a fully assembled (or one seamless body without multiple parts) product from the factory.

I think *prefabricated* is the word for structures so I guess that's not the correct one.

Comment: With regard to your question, this used to be called a "kit", though I suspect that a sexier term has been used of late.

Comment: I would say "*We ordered a new shed/cooling system on Friday and **the parts** arrived on Monday.*" and "*The shed/cooling system comes **in parts/as a kit** [for self-assembly].*"

Comment: Then there is, of course, "some assembly required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *kit* is a suitable word, as suggested in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/530314/what-do-you-call-equipment-delivered-as-parts-to-be-assembled-on-site#comment1294585_530314).

However, there is a sense of the word ***assembly*** that can be used as well:

> **6 a:** the fitting together of manufactured parts into a complete machine, structure, or unit of a machine
>           *the **assembly** of an automobile*
>      **b:** a collection of parts so assembled
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assembly)</sub>

Sense **6a** is the sense used in the term *assembly line*, but sense **6b** is used to refer to the partially constructed item as it moves through the line.

> An **assembly line** is a manufacturing process (often called a *progressive assembly*) in which parts (usually interchangeable parts) are added as the semi-finished ***assembly*** moves from workstation to workstation where the parts are added in sequence until the final ***assembly*** is produced.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_line)</sub>